# exercise package: use alphabetical counter for questions

Tags: exercises

I'm using the `exercise` package, and instead of Questions of an exercise being numbered, I'd like them to use letters, for instance a. ,  b. ,  c. and so on.

I tried to use

```
\renewcommand\theQuestion{\alph{Question}}
```

but it didn't change anything. Not sure which counter I'm supposed to change...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise} % for exercise environment
\renewcommand\theQuestion{\alph{Question}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\Question first question.
\Question second question.
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the solution by realizing that I could redefine the `\QuestionNB` command as such:

```
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\alph{Question}.\ }
\renewcommand{\theQuestion}{\alph{Question}.} % this ensures that references are also using the correct format
```

which produces the intended effect.

(In the original package the command is defined as `\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\arabic{Question}.\ }`